# How to list Azure Web Apps with dotnet SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.Models;
```

and all I'm doing is

```
var appServices = await azure.WebApps.ListAsync();
```

(stripped out the auth bit)
Whatever I try though, it's never listing any App Services / Web Apps / Functions, not even if I give the user full `Contributor` access to the Subscription.
I am 95% certain that this used to work, but it seems like a month or two ago it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I could swear this was not always like this, the `WebApps` bit is now literally that, if one wants everything then you now need to also run `await azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.ListAsync()` and so on.